# UMVUE of a function of sufficient statistic

Tags: self-study, sufficient-statistics, umvue

Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ be a random sample from the following distribution:
$$f(x\mid\theta)= \frac{4}{\theta}x^3e^{-\frac{x^4}{\theta}}$$

I know that $S = \sum X_i^4$ is a complete and sufficient statistic of $\theta$.

How can I find a UMVUE for $\tau(\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}$?

Comment: If this is for a homework or assignment, or a textbook question, please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki as we tend to treat such questions a little differently here. Welcome to CV :-)

Comment: What is the support of that density? Is there a sign missing in the exponent?

Comment: @Student001 You're right. There should be a minus into the e-power

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I leave the details for you to fill in, and do not provide proofs, because this is self-study.

---

1. Define $Y_i = X_i^4$ and find the density for the $Y_i$
2. Compute $\mathbb E Y_i$
3. Use the result in 2. to construct an estimator based on $S = \sum_iY_i$ and appeal to a theorem about unbiased estimators that are functions of complete, sufficient statistics.